# Formulating a linear program

Tags: linear-programming

[image]

I can't figure out a geometric interpretation of what this question wants. I thought maybe it was akin to a line of best fit but I am not sure. 
An
d $f(x_1)$ the value of the function at $x_1$, but isn't that the same as $y_1$, so wouldn't $f(x_1)-y_1=0?$

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider that the $x$-axis is horizontal and that the $y$-axis is vertical. Here, we know a set of 3 vertices $(x_i,y_i)_{i=1\dots3}$ of the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ (*red points on the figure*). We want to find the two parameters $a$ and $b$ of the function $f:x\mapsto ax+b$ (*black line*) that minimize the $\infty$-[norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) of the difference between the *red dots* $(x_i,y_i)_{i=1\dots3}$ and the *blue squares* $(x_i,f(x_i))_{i=1\dots3}$. So yes, it consists in finding the best-fit line in $\infty$-norm.

[image]

Mathematically, the problem to solve is finding $(a^*,b^*)$ such that
$$
(a^*,b^*) = \underset{(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2}{\arg\min}\, \|a \boldsymbol{x} + b - \boldsymbol{y}\|_{\infty}
\, ,
$$
where $\boldsymbol{x} = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $\boldsymbol{y} = (y_1,y_2,y_3)$, i.e.
$$
(a^*,b^*) = \underset{(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2}{\arg\min}\, \max_{i\in\lbrace 1\dots3\rbrace} |a x_i + b - y_i| \, .
$$

Comment: So the line I construct has equation y=ax+b. I can construct formulas for the distance between those 3 points and y=ax+b. Am I trying to minimize the average? Is that the same as minimizing the maximum?

Comment: If you minimize $\sum_i |a x_i + b - y_i|$ it is a minimization of the $1$-norm. Here, you are asked to minimize $\max_i |a x_i + b - y_i|$, i.e. the $\infty$-norm.